# How to create Pintrest navbar in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

Guys I am trying to replicate this Pintrest navbar but it is complicated
[image]

**The question is how can I add the search bar and icons on the top all aligned?**

This is what I tried so far:

```
library(shiny); library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- navbarPage("App Icon",
                
                 tabPanel('Pagina Inicial',
                          id = 'pag_inicial'
                 ),
                 tabPanel('Explore',
                          id = 'explorar'),
                 
                 tabPanel('Create',
                          id = 'criar'),
                 
                 tabPanel(
                   id = 'search_bar',
                   searchInput(
                     inputId = "searchText_shinyWidget",
                     label = NULL,
                     placeholder = "Search",
                     btnSearch = icon("magnifying-glass"),
                     btnReset = icon("xmark"),
                     value = 'Choice 1',
                     resetValue = 'Choice 2'
                   )
                 ),
                 
                 tabPanel(
                   id = 'icons',
                   div(
                     style = 'width: 40px; height: 40px;background: black;'
                   )),
                   
                 tabPanel(
                   id = 'icons',
                   div(
                     style = 'width: 40px; height: 40px;background: black;'
                   )),
                 
                 
                 tabPanel(
                   id = 'icons',
                   div(
                     style = 'width: 40px; height: 40px;background: black;'
                   ))            
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you notice the search bar is inside of tabPanel function. This is weird.

I would have to use css to kind of hide this. But it stills not the best solution.

Any help?

Comment: I think your spelling is incorrect. https://www.pinterest.com/

Comment: Also, your example is not executable since not all needed libraries are provided.